# how to make thumbnails with php

Tags: php

I was just wondering how I can make thumbnails of images stored in hdd and use them in an html page, also I need the thumbnails to be able to enlarge (to their original size) if clicked on preferably inside  a div tag on the same page, I would appreciate if anyone could put me in the right direction

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You will need the GD extension enabled. The following code will create a thumbnail file in a subdirectory called `~tmb` for a JPEG, PNG and GIF file:

```
$invalid = true;
if ($file != '.' and $file != '..') {
    if (filetype($path_abs.$file) == "file") {
        $ext = strtolower(substr($file,strrpos($file,'.')+1));
        if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
            $origimg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path_abs.$file);
        } elseif ($ext == 'png') {
            $origimg = @imagecreatefrompng($path_abs.$file);
        } elseif ($ext == 'gif') {
            $origimg = @imagecreatefromgif($path_abs.$file);
        }
        if ($origimg !== false) {
            $nheight = 0;
            $nwidth = 0;
            $use_orig = false;
            if ($width<=160 and $height<160) {
                $nwidth = $width;
                $nheight = $height;
                $use_orig = true;
                $invalid = false;
            } else {
                if ($width>$height and $width>0) {
                    $nheight = intval((160 / $width) * $height);
                    $nwidth = 160;
                } elseif ($height>0) {
                    $nwidth = intval((160 / $height) * $width);
                    $nheight = 160;
                } else {
                    $image = false;
                }
                if ($nheight > 0 and $nwidth > 0) {
                    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nwidth, $nheight);
                    $bgc = imagecolorallocate ($newimg, 238, 238, 238);
                    imagefilledrectangle ($newimg, 0, 0, $nwidth, $nheight, $bgc);
                    if (@imagecopyresampled($newimg, $origimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nwidth, $nheight, $width, $height)) {
                        $image = imagejpeg($newimg, $path_abs.'~tmb/'.$file);
                        $invalid = false;
                    } elseif (@imagecopyresized($newimg, $origimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nwidth, $nheight, $width, $height)) {
                        $image = imagejpeg($newimg, $path_abs.'~tmb/'.$file);
                        $invalid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!$invalid) {
    if ($use_orig) {
        echo '<img src="'.$file.'" alt="" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="~tmb/'.$file.'" alt="" />';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Error for file '.$file.'</p>';
}
```

In the above code, it resizes them to 160x160, though maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Note the background color (`$bgc`): for my purpose, I needed it to match the site style. You should also take some care for the file string that is supplied, ensuring the script can't exit the image path.

Comment: you'd better use pathinfo to check for the extension.

Answer (score 3):

The [gd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library allows you to manipulate images.
You will find an article to generate thumbnails [here](http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/).

If you want to allow your users to view the thumbnail and the original size, the best way is to keep the two versions.
And to display either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

its so simple,if you have any queries mail at karthid@in.com

```
$ffmpeg = "ffmpeg Installed path"

$flvfile = "source video file with root path"

$png_path " "Destination video file with root path and file type"

exec("$ffmpeg -y -i $flvfile -vframes 1 -ss 00:01:60 -an -vcodec png -f rawvideo -s 110x90 $png_path");
```

all the best....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GD library in PHP to load and resize your images to generate the thumbnails

http://us.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the PECL extension Imagick. It's usually installable with standard package-managers.

https://www.php.net/Imagick

You can either dynamically create the thumbnails and serve them using .php files (slow) or make a thumbnail-copy that you store on the server (prefered)

Answer (score 0):

the best way I found is to use the phpThumb class (http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).

It has everything you need and more, including caching, filters, watermarks and other cool stuff. Just look at the demo page.

Answer (score 0):

[maxImageUpload](http://www.phpf1.com/product/image-upload-script.html) is useful for creating thumbnails, normal image with an original image.

You can use [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) to enlarge the thumbnail image.

Comment: why would you enlarge a thumbnail? the thumb will look like crap

Comment: The enlarging image is not the thumbnailed one rather original image. I preferred to use jQuery for enlarging options.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience GD is not very memory-effective for large images, so I strongly encourage you to use Imagick. I`ve written a code snippet for [thumbnail generation with php](http://awordpress.net/blog/generate-thumbnails-with-php-imagick/) using the Imagick library. You can modify it to save the image instead of echoing it using http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php