# PHP: Resize/making thumbnails?

Tags: php

Helo i now have finish making my upload profilephoto system. Now i want include creating thumbnails of the uploaded image in different sizes eg 48x48 and 148x50, how can i do this?

Example / good tutorials for this?

Comment: Did you search for it on Google? http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20thumbnail

Comment: Dozens and dozens of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+thumbnails

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make thumbnails with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525528/how-to-make-thumbnails-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use PHP's GD library or ImageMagick library.

First find out which, if any, you have installed on your development and production environments.

Then start looking for tutorials depending on which one you want to use. There are many out there.

GD usually comes pre-packed with PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

Back then I used imagemagick.

```
$ convert -resize 48x48 xyz.jpg xyz_48x48.jpg
```

It is also available as a php module: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

But I haven't used that one, but I suppose it knows exactly the same as the command line variant.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial with [imagecreatefrom()... , imagecopyresized(), imagejpeg()](http://www.vipercreations.com/tutorials/PHP/22.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here my class for resizing. Replace the `150` occurences with a variable.

```
<?php

/**
 * Takes an image and creates a thumbnail of it.
 */
class ImageThumbnail
{
    private $thumbnail;


    /**
     * Create a new object
     *
     * @param string $source Location of the original image (can be null if set using create())
     * @param string $extension File extension, if it has been obfuscated (e.g. moved to PHP's tmp dir)
     */
    public function __construct($source, $extension)
    {
        if ($source)
        {
            $this->create($source, $extension);
        }
    }


    public function create($source, $extension = null)
    {
        if (!$extension)
        {
            $parts = explode('.', $source); // get the file extension
            $extension = array_pop($parts);
        }
        else
        {
            $extension = ltrim($extension, '.'); // get rid of any prefixing dots
        }


        // Get the images size
        $size = getImageSize($source);

        // Width > height
        if ($size[0] > $size[1])
        {
            $width = 150;
            $height = (int) (150 * $size[1] / $size[0]);
        }
        // Height > width
        else
        {
            $width = (int) (150 * $size[0] / $size[1]);
            $height = 150;
        }

        $readFunc = 'imageCreateFrom'.filenameToImageMime($source);
        if (!$source = $readFunc($source))
        {
            throw new Exception('The source image is unreadable');
        }

        // Create an blank image for the thumbnail
        $thumbnail = imageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);

        // Copy source image onto new image
        imageCopyResized($thumbnail, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);

        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    }


    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }


    public function move($target)
    {
        $func = 'image'.filenameToImageMime($target);
        $func($this->thumbnail, $target);
        imageDestroy($this->thumbnail);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Notinlist - There is only a single "magic number", which isn't exactly magic when it's part of my own library for a specific task.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function makenicepic($srcfile,$tofile,$maxwidth,$maxheight) {
    //global $_SGLOBAL;
// check file exist
if (!file_exists($srcfile)) {
    return '';
}
$dstfile = $tofile;

include_once(S_ROOT.'./data/data_setting.php');

// //size
$tow = $maxwidth;
$toh =$maxheight;

$make_max = 0;
$maxtow = 950;
$maxtoh = 700;
$make_max = 1;


$im = '';
if($data = getimagesize($srcfile)) {
    if($data[2] == 1) {
        $make_max = 0;//gif skip
        if(function_exists("imagecreatefromgif")) {
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($srcfile);
        }
    } elseif($data[2] == 2) {
        if(function_exists("imagecreatefromjpeg")) {
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcfile);
        }
    } elseif($data[2] == 3) {
        if(function_exists("imagecreatefrompng")) {
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($srcfile);
        }
    }
}
if(!$im) return '';

$srcw = imagesx($im);
$srch = imagesy($im);

$towh = $tow/$toh;
$srcwh = $srcw/$srch;
if($towh <= $srcwh){
    $ftow = $tow;
    $ftoh = $ftow*($srch/$srcw);

    $fmaxtow = $maxtow;
    $fmaxtoh = $fmaxtow*($srch/$srcw);
} else {
    $ftoh = $toh;
    $ftow = $ftoh*($srcw/$srch);

    $fmaxtoh = $maxtoh;
    $fmaxtow = $fmaxtoh*($srcw/$srch);
}
if($srcw <= $maxtow && $srch <= $maxtoh) {
    $make_max = 0;
}
if($srcw > $tow || $srch > $toh) {
    if(function_exists("imagecreatetruecolor") && function_exists("imagecopyresampled") && @$ni = imagecreatetruecolor($ftow, $ftoh)) {
        imagecopyresampled($ni, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ftow, $ftoh, $srcw, $srch);

        if($make_max && @$maxni = imagecreatetruecolor($fmaxtow, $fmaxtoh)) {
            imagecopyresampled($maxni, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fmaxtow, $fmaxtoh, $srcw, $srch);
        }
    } elseif(function_exists("imagecreate") && function_exists("imagecopyresized") && @$ni = imagecreate($ftow, $ftoh)) {
        imagecopyresized($ni, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ftow, $ftoh, $srcw, $srch);

        if($make_max && @$maxni = imagecreate($fmaxtow, $fmaxtoh)) {
            imagecopyresized($maxni, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fmaxtow, $fmaxtoh, $srcw, $srch);
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }
    if(function_exists('imagejpeg')) {
        imagejpeg($ni, $dstfile);
        //big pic
        if($make_max) {
            imagejpeg($maxni, $srcfile);
        }
    } elseif(function_exists('imagepng')) {
        imagepng($ni, $dstfile);

        if($make_max) {
            imagepng($maxni, $srcfile);
        }
    }
    imagedestroy($ni);
    if($make_max) {
        imagedestroy($maxni);
    }
}
imagedestroy($im);

if(!file_exists($dstfile)) {
    return '';
} else {
    return $dstfile;
}
```

}