# PHP code for generating thumbnails

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make thumbnails with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525528/how-to-make-thumbnails-with-php)

I have a php upload script that enables users to upload images to a folder on an ftp server. I am after (if possible) some code for a web page that creates thumbnails of the images and then lets the user click on each of these images and the full image is displayed.

I have found some pages via google with descriptions to this effect, yet haven't found an easy way to do this.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out Timthumb

http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Examples:

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/demo/timthumb-basic/

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this before. Check out [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setOption('jpeg:size', '800x532');
$image->readImage('foo.jpg');
```